# How to show a dropdown list on a contentEditable span/div item when user tries to change the text of span

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable span element defined as:

```
<span contentEditable={this.props.enableEditColumn} onKeyPress={this.checkInput.bind(this,columnDef)}>
                    {displayContent}
</span>
```

The checkInput function is responsible for checking if a number or letter can be inputted. 
In the following image, highlighted 'Holmes' is editable. If I enter another character, or delete and start typing, I need to be able to show a list of names in a dropdown that should popup there.

[image: editable],

The selected value would then become the span/div text.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that a `contenteditible` element supports a `keypress` event. It may support an `input` event.

Comment: onKeyPress works!

Answer (score 0):

try it https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_dropdown_hover
but I could not understand exactly what you want.
I think this may help you, just send it again.
NOTE: I'm Brazilian I'm using google translate

Comment: I want a dropdown to trigger only when a user enters some text in the span item.

Answer (score 0):

There is great plugin called draft.js. It has a mentions addon that helps with this. If you need help with the draft.js plugin just message me and I will help. Been using it for months and will respond quickly